Do the characters in Coheed and Cambria's "Searching for Tomorrow" video reference The Amory Wars?
In the music video for Coheed and Cambria's song Searching for Tomorrow (2024), several characters appear that could reference either the band's sci-fi universe, The Amory Wars, or other works. For context, Coheed and Cambria are known for creating concept albums that tell the ongoing story of The Amory Wars.




Among these characters is a cyborg figure who bears a striking resemblance to RoboCop and could potentially be General Mayo Deftinwolf, one of the main antagonists from The Amory Wars.

Another notable character is a construction worker in high-visibility gear operating a jackhammer, who appears to be a representation of Claudio Sanchez, the band's lead singer and guitarist, as well as co-creator of The Amory Wars. This worker seems to be a clever reference to the lyrics "Man your own jackhammer!" from their song In Keeping Secrets of Silent Earth: 3. Within The Amory Wars universe, jackhammer is the term used for the Red Army weapon that functions as both a starship and an artillery battery.

I'm curious whether these character appearances are references to The Amory Wars lore, callbacks to previous Coheed and Cambria songs, or perhaps nods to other works.
